# Maximum value of the function $\frac{1}{2}x^2(k-x)$ with $x \in [0,k]$

Tags: calculus, optimization

This is an optimization problem, where the decrease in blood pressure of a person depends on the dosage x in mg that they take of a medication.

The steps I've taken:

1. Note that the extremes of the interval aren't relevant for the question, since the decrease in pressure will be 0.
2. Derive the function and equal it to 0
3. Find that x is 2/3 of K

Is this the right way to go about it? How to put it into proper mathematical terms?

Comment: If the unconstrained minimum satisfies all the constraints, you don't need to worry about them. You must check that you get a minimum and not some other stationary point (max, saddle point), though ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your approach works fine. Alternatively, observe that: $f(x) = 2\cdot\dfrac{x}{2}\cdot \dfrac{x}{2}\cdot (k-x)\le 2\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{x}{2}+(k-x)}{3}\right)^3= \dfrac{2k^3}{27}$, by AM-GM inequality. This maximum value occurs when $\dfrac{x}{2} = k - x\implies x = \dfrac{2k}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

The Extreme value theorem states that if a function is continuous on a closed interval [a,b], then the function must have a maximum and a minimum on the interval.
From this let's calculate the extremes of the function, that's it the zeros of deritative:
$$f'(x)=x(k-x)-\frac{x^2}{2}=0\iff x=0\;, x=\frac{2k}{3}$$

Both of them in our intervalo. So $f(0)=0$ and $f(2k/3)=\frac{2k^3}{27}$. The function uncrease from value $0$ at zero to the maximum value at $2k/3$. From that point it decreases to the value $0$ at $k$.

Comment: Note that the extrema are either among the critical points ($f'(x)=0$) or among the bounds $x=0,x=k$ So $f(k)=0$ should not be overlooked (OP did consider it).

Comment: Yes, it pointed it to ilustrate the tendence of the function in the interval